# Matcaffe on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: matlab, caffe, ubuntu-16.04, matcaffe

I have been trying to compile Matcaffe in Ubuntu 16.04. I could successfully compile caffe and pycaffe (using gcc 5). However since Ubuntu 16.04 comes with gcc 5, and MATLAB  R2016b is compatible with gcc 4.9, I got following warning during compilation (using *make matcafee*):

> MEX matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.cpp Building with 'g++'.  Warning:
>   You are using gcc version '5.4.0'. The version of gcc is not
>   supported. The version currently supported with MEX is '4.9.x'. For a
>   list of currently supported compilers see:
>   http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release.  MEX
>   completed successfully.

Even though the MEX file is created, I can not use it from MATLAB because it does not recognize them.

To resolve this issue, I installed the gcc 4.9 and g++ 4.9 and updated the symbolic links to use them. When I try to compile matcaffe, I get the following error message:

> MEX matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.cpp Building with 'g++'.
>   /tmp/mex_286607035953408_13265/caffe_.o: In function
>   `net_copy_from(int, mxArray_tag**, int, mxArray_tag const**)':
>   caffe_.cpp:(.text+0x167d): undefined reference to`
>   caffe::Net::CopyTrainedLayersFrom(std::string)'
>   /tmp/mex_286607035953408_13265/caffe_.o: In function `get_net(int,
>   mxArray_tag**, int, mxArray_tag const**)': caffe_.cpp:(.text+0x182b):
>   undefined reference to`caffe::Net::Net(std::string const&,
>   caffe::Phase, int, std::vector > const*, caffe::Net const*)'
>   /tmp/mex_286607035953408_13265/caffe_.o: In function `get_solver(int,
>   mxArray_tag**, int, mxArray_tag const**)': caffe_.cpp:(.text+0x343f):
>   undefined reference to`
>   caffe::ReadSolverParamsFromTextFileOrDie(std::string const&,
>   caffe::SolverParameter*)' /tmp/mex_286607035953408_13265/caffe_.o: In
>   function `std::string* google::MakeCheckOpString<int, int>(int const&,
>   int const&, char const*)':
>   caffe_.cpp:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x42):
>   undefined reference to`
>   google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString()'
>   /tmp/mex_286607035953408_13265/caffe_.o: In function `std::string*
>   google::MakeCheckOpString<unsigned long, int>(unsigned long const&,
>   int const&, char const*)':
>   caffe_.cpp:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringImiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringImiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x42):
>   undefined reference to`
>   google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString()' collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status
>
> Makefile:511: recipe for target 'matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64'
>   failed make: *** [matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64] Error 255

Has anyone successfully compiled Matcaffe on Ubuntu 16.04? 
I also tried the same procedure with MATLAB R2014b and gcc 4.7 but without any success.

Answer (score 1):

Caffe is compiled against the system version of libstdc++ and opencv, but linking to the matlab version when running matcaffe. I solved this expediently by appending

```
export LD_PRELOAD=${LD_PRELOAD}:/usr/local/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

to `~/.bashrc` and disabling opencv (uncomment `USE_OPENCV := 0` in `Makefile.config`) when building Caffe.